# Printing a listview, loop next line

Tags: c#, sql, listview, printing

I want to print a list view.
I want it to go to the next line when i print. (It Stays on the same line and writes over the (===)
Please submit a code if u can
Please!
  [ But This is what the output is when I print it to a XPS Document[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWcbJ.png)

```
       {

         this.Hide();
         try
         {
             PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();

             PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();

             printDialog.Document = printDocument;        

             printDocument.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(CreateReceipt); 


             DialogResult result = printDialog.ShowDialog();

             if (result == DialogResult.OK)
             {
                 printDocument.Print();

             }
             if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
             {
                 Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
                 fr2.Show();
             }
         }
         catch
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Error, Occured While Printing");
             Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
             fr2.Show();
         }
         this.Show();
     }


     public void CreateReceipt(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
     {
         Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;

         Font font = new Font("Courier New", 12); 

         float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();

         int startX = 10;
         int startY = 10;
         int offset = 40;

         offset = offset + (int)fontHeight;

         {

             graphic.DrawString("Bill Flow", new Font("Courier New", 18), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);
             string top = "Item Name".PadRight(15) + "Price".PadRight(12) + "Quantity";
             graphic.DrawString(top, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
             offset = offset + (int)fontHeight;
             graphic.DrawString("-----------------------------------------------", font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);


         }


         {

             StringBuilder listViewContent = new StringBuilder();

             listViewContent.ToString();

//THIS IS THE PART WHERE ITS WRONG I GUESS

             {
                 for (int item = 0; item < this.listView1.Items.Count; item++)
                 {
                     for (int subitem = 0;
                        subitem < this.listView1.Columns.Count;
                        subitem++)
                     {
                         listViewContent.Append
                         (this.listView1.Items[item].SubItems[subitem].Text);
                         if (subitem < this.listView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                             listViewContent.Append("   ");
                     }
                     string ln;

                     ln = listViewContent.ToString();

                     graphic.DrawString(ln+"\n", new Font("Courier New", 12, FontStyle.Italic), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), startX, startY + offset);
                     this.Show();

                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Please include a complete, but minimal snippet of code. We have no idea how to help you with the two large, but still incomplete code blocks in your question. See this for more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Does all the text appear? You ought to include a check for null! And, probably your current issue: after each \n you print you need to advance the y-offset or else each new line is printed on top of the last one.. Also: Try to improve your formatting and remove the sql Tag!